# Component is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building an angular 4 application. I am getting error

```
Error:Component HomeComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
```

I have created HomeModule and HomeComponent. Which one do I need to refer to the AppModule? I am a bit confused. Do I need to refer HomeModule or HomeComponent? Ultimately what I am looking for is when the user clicks the Home menu, he should be directed to the home.component.html which will be rendered on the index page.

App.module is:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { TopbarComponent } from './topbar/topbar.component';
import { FooterbarComponent } from './footerbar/footerbar.component';
import { MRDBGlobalConstants } from './shared/mrdb.global.constants';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';
import { HomeModule } from './Home/home.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FooterbarComponent,
    TopbarComponent,
    NavbarComponent

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HomeModule

  ],
  providers: [MRDBGlobalConstants],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

HomeModule is:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [HomeComponent],
  declarations: [HomeComponent]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

HomeComponent is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: do you use lazy loading?

Comment: Yes. How do i do it with lazy loading

Comment: add `HomeComponent` to `entryComponents`

Comment: What do you mean by entryComponents

Comment: read [here](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#when-do-i-add-components-to-entrycomponents) and here is how you do it: `@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [HomeComponent],
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  entryComponents: [HomeComponent]
})`

Comment: in my case, I imported component twice once in main module entryComponent, and other in lazy load module declarations. that causing error

Answer (score 109):

If your are not using lazy loading, you need to import your HomeComponent in app.module and mention it under declarations. Also, don't forget to remove from imports

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http'

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { TopbarComponent } from './topbar/topbar.component';
import { FooterbarComponent } from './footerbar/footerbar.component';
import { MRDBGlobalConstants } from './shared/mrdb.global.constants';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app.routing';
import {HomeModule} from './Home/home.module';
// import HomeComponent here

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FooterbarComponent,
    TopbarComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    // add HomeComponent here
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HomeModule  // remove this

  ],
  providers: [MRDBGlobalConstants],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I still get the error Component HomeComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.

Comment: Check if your path from where you are importing has the component there. Maybe it will be easy to find out if you could update your current code here

Comment: What about if you  are using Lazy Loading?

Comment: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html  - this link might be helpful if someone wants to use lazy loading

Comment: Yeah doesn't this defeat the purpose of having HomeModule?

Answer (score 62):

In my case, I only need to restart the server (that is if you're using `ng serve`).

It happens to me every time I add a new module while the server is running.

Comment: *bang head* New to Angular and this bit me.  Restarted the server and it worked great.

Answer (score 26):

In my case, I was missing my new generated component in the `declarations` at `app.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ....
    NewGeneratedComponent, //this was missing
    ....
  ],
  imports: [
    ....
```

Comment: Been messing around with lazy loading features and ended up commenting it. Thanks!

Comment: This was the answer for me!  Also, if it's a routing component, then set declarations in app-routing-module.ts

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. The reason was because I created a component while my server was still running.
The solution is to quit the server and ng serve again.

Answer (score 8):

The usual cause IF you are using lazy loading and [function form import statements](https://angular.io/api/router/LoadChildrenCallback) is importing the *routing module* instead of the *page module*. So:

**Incorrect**:

`loadChildren: () => import('./../home-routing.module').then(m => m.HomePageRoutingModule)`

**Correct**:

`loadChildren: () => import('./../home.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule)`

You might get away with this for a while, but eventually it will cause problems.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this error message on 2 separate occasions, with lazy loading in Angular 7 and the above did not help. For both of the below to work you MUST stop and restart ng serve for it to completely update correctly.

1) First time I had somehow incorrectly imported my AppModule into the lazy loaded feature module. I removed this import from the lazy loaded module and it started working again.

2) Second time I had a separate CoreModule that I was importing into the AppModule AND same lazy loaded module as #1. I removed this import from the lazy loaded module and it started working again.

Basically, check your hierarchy of imports and pay close attention to the order of the imports (if they are imported where they should be). Lazy loaded modules only need their own route component / dependencies. App and parent dependencies will be passed down whether they are imported into AppModule, or imported from another feature module that is NOT-lazy loaded and already imported in a parent module.

Answer (score 5):

In my case the imports of real routes in `app.component.spec.ts` were causing these error messages. Solution was to import `RouterTestingModule` instead.

```js
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    console.log(fixture);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));

});
```

Answer (score 4):

**Angular lazy loading**

In my case I forgot and re-imported a component that is already part of imported child module in routing.ts.

```
....
...
 {
path: "clients",
component: ClientsComponent,
loadChildren: () =>
  import(`./components/users/users.module`).then(m => m.UsersModule)
}
.....
..
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same issue and none of what I was seeing here was working.  If you are listing your Component in the app-routing.module issue you may have run into the same problem I was having.

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { TopbarComponent } from './topbar/topbar.component';
import { FooterbarComponent } from './footerbar/footerbar.component';
import { MRDBGlobalConstants } from './shared/mrdb.global.constants';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app.routing';
import {HomeModule} from './Home/home.module';
// import HomeComponent here

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FooterbarComponent,
    TopbarComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    // add HomeComponent here
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HomeModule  // remove this

  ],
  providers: [MRDBGlobalConstants],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

home/index.ts

```
export * from './';
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'app/home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'app/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'app/home' }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

home/home.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
// import { HomeComponent } from './home.component'; This would cause app to break
import { HomeComponent } from './';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [HomeComponent],
  declarations: [HomeComponent]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

I won't claim to understand exactly why this is the case, but when using indexing to export components (and I would assume the same for services, etc.), when referencing the same component in separate modules you need to import them from the same file, in this case the index, in order to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Check your Lazy module , i have imported AppRoutingModule  in the lazy module. After removing the import and  imports of AppRoutingModule, Mine started working.

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from '../app-routing.module';
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Angular 6, I renamed folder and file names of my modules **from google.map.module.ts to google-map.module.ts.**
In order to compile without overlay with old module and component names, ng compiler compiled with no error.
[image]

In app.routes.ts:

```
     {
        path: 'calendar', 
        loadChildren: './views/app-calendar/app-calendar.module#AppCalendarModule', 
        data: { title: 'Calendar', breadcrumb: 'CALENDAR'}
      },
```

In google-map.routing.ts

```
import { GoogleMapComponent } from './google-map.component';
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: GoogleMapComponent, data: { title: 'Coupon Map' }
  }
];
@NgModule({
    exports: [RouterModule],
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)]
})
export class GoogleMapRoutingModule { }
```

In google-map.module.ts:

```
import { GoogleMapRoutingModule } from './google-map.routing';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    GoogleMapRoutingModule,
  ],
  exports: [GoogleMapComponent],
  declarations: [GoogleMapComponent]
})
export class GoogleMapModule { }
```

Comment: This unfortunately solved the issue, but I really don't get it why the `<Custom>RouterModule` has to export the component.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue.
I had created another component with the same name under a different folder.
so in my app module I had to import both components but with a trick

`import {DuplicateComponent as AdminDuplicateComponent} from '/the/path/to/the/component';`

Then in declarations I could add AdminDuplicateComponent instead.

Just thought that I would leave that there for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by simple two steps:

Add your componnet(HomeComponent) to `declarations` array `entryComponents` array.

> As this component is accesses neither throw selector nor router,
>   adding this to entryComponnets array is important

see how to do:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ....
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    ...

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [HomeComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was moving the component `UserComponent` from one module `appModule` to another`dashboardModule` and forgot to remove the route definition from the routing of the previous module`appModule` in AppRoutingModule file.

```
const routes = [
 { path: 'user', component: UserComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},...]
```

After i removed the route definition it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because I had same name of component in 2 different modules. One solution is if its shared use the exporting technique etc but in my case both had to be named same but the purpose was different.

**The Real Issue**

So while importing component B, the intellisense imported the path of Component A so I had to choose 2nd option of the component path from intellisense and that resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using lazy loading then must load that module in any router module , like in app-routing.module.ts {path:'home',loadChildren:'./home.module#HomeModule'}

Answer (score 0):

My case is same as @7guyo mentioned. I'm using lazyloading and was unconsiously doing this:

```
import { component1Route } from './path/component1.route';

export const entityState: Routes = [
{
   path: 'home',
   children: component1Route
}]
```

Instead of:

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
   RouterModule.forChild([
   {
     path: '',
     loadChildren: () => import('./component1/component1.module').then(m => m.ComponentOneModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./component2/component2.module').then(m => m.ComponentTwoModule)
  }])
  ]})

  export class MainModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use lazy load you need to delete your component's module and routing module from app module. If you don't, it'll try to load them when app started and throws that error.

```js
@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      AppComponent
   ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      FormsModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
      // YourComponentModule,
      // YourComponentRoutingModule
   ],
   bootstrap: [
      AppComponent
   ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i imported wrong,
In module place instead of importing module(DemoModule) imported routing module(DemoRoutingModule)

Wrong Import:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
  path: '', component: ContentComponent,
  children: [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'demo' },
  { path: 'demo', loadChildren : () => import('../content/demo/demo-routing.module').then(m => m.DemoRoutingModule)}]
  }
];
```

Right Code

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
  path: '', component: ContentComponent,
  children: [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'demo' },
  { path: 'demo', loadChildren : () => import('../content/demo/demo.module').then(m => m.DemoModule)}]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify your component is properly imported in app-routing.module.ts. In my case that was the reason

Answer (score 0):

In Some case the same may happen when you have created a module for HomeComponent  and in app-routing.module you directly given both

**component: HomeComponent,
loadChildren:"./modules/.../HomeModule.module#HomeModule"** in Routes array.

when we try lazy loading we do give loadChildren attribute only.

Answer (score -1):

Prerequisites:
 1. If you have multiple Modules
 2. And you are using a component (suppose DemoComponent) from a different module (suppose AModule), in a different module (suppose BModule)

Then Your AModule should be

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [DemoComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [AModule]
})
export class AModule{ }
```

and your BModule should be

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule, AModule
  ],
  exports: [],
})
export class BModule { }
```