# NativeScript white screen on launch after adding routing

Tags: angular2-nativescript

I'm writing my first app in NativeScript and I'm not too familiar with front-end development. I've just started, and created a simple first screen with two buttons. When pressing on a button it should navigate to another screen. I've added a Route based on the basic tutorial, but now the app is simply not showing anything. I'm not sure how I can debug the problem or see any log / error that can help me figure out where's the problem. 
Here's my code:

app.routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";

const routes: Routes = [
   { path: "", redirectTo: "/home", pathMatch: "full" },
   { path: "home", loadChildren: "./home/home.module#HomeModule" },

];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

home-routing-module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";

import { HomeComponent } from "./home.component";
import { MathComponent } from "../math/math.component";

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", component: HomeComponent },
    { path: "math", component: MathComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }

export const navigatableComponents = [
    MathComponent
];
```

home.component.html

```
<GridLayout>
    <ScrollView class="page">
        <StackLayout class="home-panel">
            <Label textWrap="true" text="Test" class="h2 description-label"></Label>
            <Button text="Math" (tap)="onMathTap()"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
     </ScrollView>
</GridLayout>
```

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
    selector: "Home",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./home.component.html",
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
 export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    onMathTap(): void {
        console.log("Math was pressed");
        this.router.navigate(["/math"])
    }


    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
}
```

app.modules.ts

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in you AppComponent template(html). [Official doc](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet) refer this [link](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/angular-navigation#router-outlet) also

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I'm not sure I understand where and how to add it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` as the first line of your app.component.html

Comment: Added to the original question.

Comment: Did you add the router outlet to the app.component.html? its still not working?

Comment: It didn't help. I've posted below the solution that did work. Thanks for your help!   I still have a problem with my code that when pressing the button it's not navigating anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

This answer was the solution for me:
[Component is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44827999/component-is-not-part-of-any-ngmodule-or-the-module-has-not-been-imported-into-y)

I've added in home.module.ts the components I want to navigate to in the NgModules declarations.

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptCommonModule } from "nativescript-angular/common";
import { NativeScriptUISideDrawerModule } from "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/angular";
import { NativeScriptUIListViewModule } from "nativescript-ui-listview/angular";
import { NativeScriptUICalendarModule } from "nativescript-ui-calendar/angular";
import { NativeScriptUIChartModule } from "nativescript-ui-chart/angular";
import { NativeScriptUIDataFormModule } from "nativescript-ui-dataform/angular";
import { NativeScriptUIAutoCompleteTextViewModule } from "nativescript-ui- autocomplete/angular";
import { NativeScriptUIGaugeModule } from "nativescript-ui-gauge/angular";
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";

import { HomeRoutingModule } from "./home-routing.module";
import { HomeComponent } from "./home.component";
import { MathComponent } from "../math/math.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NativeScriptUISideDrawerModule,
        NativeScriptUIListViewModule,
        NativeScriptUICalendarModule,
        NativeScriptUIChartModule,
        NativeScriptUIDataFormModule,
        NativeScriptUIAutoCompleteTextViewModule,
        NativeScriptUIGaugeModule,
        NativeScriptCommonModule,
        HomeRoutingModule,
        NativeScriptFormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        HomeComponent,
        MathComponent,
    ],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

The navigation when pressing a button is still not working for me, but at least the app is launching.